# Unable to read the data array of a class

Tags: jquery

I have got the id with the help of the id i am trying to read the data of a class

this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bxbnkq64/4/

This is my code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var vendor_item_id = 'lastwrap7';
     var vendoritemsdata =  $('.lastItm_Wrap').find("#" + vendor_item_id).data('stuff');

    alert(vendoritemsdata.length);
});
```

Could you please tell me how to read the value in this case??

Comment: Why are you using `find()` with ID selector as argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.lastItm_Wrap` element also has the `#lastwrap7` `id` on it. This means that `find()` won't work as it only looks for child elements. Instead, as `id` attributes should be unique, you can remove the `find()` call completely. Try this:

```
var vendoritemsdata = $("#" + vendor_item_id).data('stuff');
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxbnkq64/5/)

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is if the target element has the attribute `id` then you can use that directly instead of `.find()`ing it from the parent.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var vendor_item_id = 'lastwrap7';
     var vendoritemsdata =  $("#" + vendor_item_id).data('stuff');

    alert(vendoritemsdata.length);
});
```

and issue with your code:

1. You are finding an element which is not inside.
2. and same element has both the class name and the id *which you are finding*.